# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed during fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

While using fragments I got following exception:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException`: Activity has been destroyed

The code is as follows:

```
 try {
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

DrawerItemClickListener.java

```
public class DrawerItemClickListener extends FragmentActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }


    private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ActivitDiagnosisFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new ActivitDiagnosisFragment();
                break;
        //  case 2:
        //      fragment = new HelpFragment();
        //      break;

            default:
                break;
        }


        try {
            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);


            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This could be an error where you are trying to commit a transaction after the Activity is destroyed. FYI Fragments live inside Activity (Activity is to manage fragments), Post your Activity code in complete to come into  a solution

Comment: @Raaja SN I have shared my complete code and thanks for ur rply

Comment: Yes. I can guess the error. You are using the drawer Layout and a list view to listen for clicks and respond with a fragment transaction. But i guess for some reason the activity is destroyed when the transaction is made. There are two ways to check for the cause of the error. Just log something in OnDestroy and something while fragment transaction. Find out which logs first. Or try to set a boolean flag in onStart and set to true, set the flag to false on OnStop and check for this flag before making a transaction. In the meantime pls post ur complete Activity class in http://paste.ofcode.org

Comment: @Raaja Thanks I will check it out